# Cursor randomly skips while typing

Tags: keyboard, imac, big-sur

While typing on my 2019 iMac Magic Keyboard, frequently the cursor skips to an earlier location in the text, and I type fast enough that what I was typing ends up inserted into the earlier writing. This is annoying.

Most people reporting this have been using a Macbook with a trackpad under the keyboard, so it has been assumed that they are accidentally brushing the trackpad while typing.  That isn't the case for me - my Magic Trackpad is to the right of my keyboard - its not possible to accidentally touch it while typing.

This has been an issue for some time - but I am having to do more long-form typing so am noticing it more.  I am now running Big Sur 11.3 but it definitely was an issue with Catalina too and possibly earlier. This happens across all apps I type in, including MS Word, VS Code, and web apps in the Browser - so it seems likely an issue at the OS or hardware level.

Has anyone else experienced this and, even better, found a way to fix it.

Comment: Are the batteries on both keyboard/trackpad fully charged? Does it happen with a wired keyboard & mouse? If you have other Bluetooth devices/peripherals in close proximity, try disabling or moving them out of range.

Comment: Yes. Batteries fully charged in both. I don't have a wired keyboard to test with - the Magic Keyboard is standard issue. I don't use any other Bluetooth devices with my Mac.

Comment: Do you have any other Bluetooth devices in the immediate area around your Mac (room, apartment, house, etc)?

Comment: The issue occurs whether there are other Bluetooth devices in the vicinity or not.